# Find the first non null value in another column with arbitrary order by and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following sample data...

```
drop table if exists #data
create table #data
(
    Id char(3),
    Date1 date,
    Date2 date
)
insert into #data (Id, Date1, Date2)
values
    ('100', '2017-02-24', null),
    ('100', '2017-03-06', null),
    ('100', '2017-03-21', '2017-04-04'),
    ('100', '2017-06-15', null),
    ('100', '2017-06-16', '2017-06-16'),
    ('100', '2017-11-17', null),
    ('100', '2018-02-02', null),
    ('200', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-11'),
    ('200', '2018-02-02', null),
    ('200', '2018-02-08', null),
    ('200', '2018-02-09', null),
    ('200', '2018-02-14', '2018-02-15'),
    ('200', '2018-03-03', '2018-03-07'),
    ('200', '2018-06-07', '2018-06-14')
```

I want to create a new column `[new_date]` from the two columns `[DATE_1]` and `[DATE_2]` which takes values:

- Min of `[DATE_1]` less than `[DATE_2]` if the previous values of `[DATE_2]` are NULL.
- The MIN of `[DATE_1]` greater than `[DATE_2]` and which has a null value of `[DATE_2]`
- otherwise it is the `[DATE_1]` between the previous `[DATE_2]` and `[DATE_2]` if there is no NULL value between the previous `[Date_2]` and `[Date_2]`

For each ID and the dates should be sorted in ascending order.

I would like to obtain the result with a SQL query as shared in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You will get more answers if you include some sample data and expected results, but don't add them in an image, add them as text we can copy/paste

Comment: mysql is not the same as sql-server

Comment: Please cut and paste a **text** representation of your data into your question. If you are unsure of formatting, paste the raw data and someone can help with formatting.

Comment: Do you want a grouped result set? Or should we assume any values in `NewDate` are null when not one of the values you've indicated?

Comment: Thank you @Xedni for transcribing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to first partition the data into groups of rows, where each group ends with a non-null `DATE_2` value. This can be done using a carefully crafted `COUNT() OVER()` window function. That can be wrapped up in a Common Table Expression (CTE) that feeds a final select. The final select can conditionally select the minimum `DATE_1` value within each group using a `MIN() OVER()` window function.

Something like:

```
;WITH CTE_Grouped AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(DATE_2) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
                ORDER BY DATE_1
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ) AS GroupNum
    FROM Data D
)
SELECT
    G.ID, G.DATE_1, G.DATE_2, G.GroupNum,
    CASE WHEN G.DATE_2 IS NOT NULL
        THEN MIN(G.DATE_1) OVER(PARTITION BY G.ID, G.GroupNum)
        END AS new_date
FROM CTE_Grouped G
ORDER BY G.ID, G.DATE_1
```

Results:

| ID | DATE_1 | DATE_2 | GroupNum | new_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2017-02-24 | null | 0 | null |
| 100 | 2017-03-06 | null | 0 | null |
| 100 | 2017-03-21 | 2017-04-04 | 0 | 2017-02-24 |
| 100 | 2017-06-15 | null | 1 | null |
| 100 | 2017-06-16 | 2017-06-16 | 1 | 2017-06-15 |
| 100 | 2017-11-17 | null | 2 | null |
| 100 | 2018-02-02 | null | 2 | null |
| 200 | 2017-06-06 | 2017-06-11 | 0 | 2017-06-06 |
| 200 | 2018-02-02 | null | 1 | null |
| 200 | 2018-02-08 | null | 1 | null |
| 200 | 2018-02-09 | null | 1 | null |
| 200 | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-15 | 1 | 2018-02-02 |
| 200 | 2018-03-03 | 2018-03-07 | 2 | 2018-03-03 |
| 200 | 2018-06-07 | 2018-06-14 | 3 | 2018-06-07 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w2dt7A5l).